# <App> would like to find and connect to devices on your local network

Tags: react-native

I am getting the alert " would like to find and connect to devices on your local network" on the prod version of my React Native app (the one downloaded from the app store or from testflight).

From what I've found online, this could be due to one of the libraries we're using that requests this permission.

How would I know which library is asking for it or how could I disable this popup completely from showing up on prod?

Those are my current dependencies:

```
"@ovalmoney/react-native-fitness": "^0.5.3",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.7",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.3",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.3",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^12.7.3",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.7.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
"@sentry/react-native": "2.4.3",
"apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
"graphql": "^15.5.1",
"graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
"js-interpreter": "^2.3.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"mixpanel-react-native": "^1.3.2",
"mobx": "^5.14.0",
"mobx-react": "^5.0.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.0",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-dash": "^0.0.11",
"react-native-device-info": "^8.3.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.9.0",
"react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
"react-native-intercom": "^22.0.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.3",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.6.0",
"react-native-sensors": "^7.3.3",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
"react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
"react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
"rn-prompt": "^1.0.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

According of Official [FAQ about Local Network Privacy](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663858) - [FAQ-15: My app presents the local network privacy alert unexpectedly. Is there a way to track down the cause?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664116), you should:

> ... start removing any third-party libraries from your app until you figure out which one is triggering it, and then raise this issue with the library’s vendor.

In my case I'm not able to consistently reproduce the alert, so this method doesn't work for me though.